# D3 Transition name - What is it for?

Tags: d3.js

In the [D3.js Transition wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#d3_transition), the definition for the Transition is:

`d3.transition([selection], [name])`

What is the `name` for, and how can it be put to good use?

When would this be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this is only useful in combination with `transition.each()`:

> The interrupt event is invoked if an active transition is interrupted by another transition of the same name on the same element.

That is, if you need multiple transitions on the same element(s), you can use the `name` argument to receive interrupt events for each separately.

Comment: Thanks Lars. I will mark it as correct as far as nobody else gives insight.